# Does C++ provide a "triple" template, comparable to pair<T1, T2>?

Tags: c++, stl, std-pair

Does C++ have anything like [std::pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) but with 3 elements?

For example:

```
#include <triple.h>
triple<int, int, int> array[10];

array[1].first = 1;
array[1].second = 2;
array[1].third = 3;
```

Comment: This duplicate is worth keeping; it should not be deleted.

Answer (score 53):

You might be looking for [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple):

```
#include <tuple>

....

std::tuple<int, int, int> tpl;

std::get<0>(tpl) = 1;
std::get<1>(tpl) = 2;
std::get<2>(tpl) = 3;
```

Comment: I believe `std::tuple` has a huge drawback! It cannot be accessed by index. If all types are the same, one would probably be better off with `std::array<3>`.

Answer (score 13):

Class template `std::tuple` is a fixed-size collection of heterogeneous values, available in standard library since C++11. It is a generalization of `std::pair` and presented in header

```
#include <tuple>
```

You can read about this here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple

Example:

```
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<int, int, int> three;

std::get<0>( three) = 0;
std::get<1>( three) = 1;
std::get<2>( three) = 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't.

You can however use a [tuple](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/) or a "double pair" (`pair<pair<T1,T2>,T3>`). Or - obviously - write the class yourself (which shouldn't be hard).

Answer (score -6):

There are only 2 simple way to get that.
1) To implement it yourself.
2) get the boost and use boost::tuple http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html like this

```
double d = 2.7; A a;
tuple<int, double&, const A&> t(1, d, a);
const tuple<int, double&, const A&> ct = t;
  ...
int i = get<0>(t); i = t.get<0>();       
int j = get<0>(ct);                      
get<0>(t) = 5;
```

Comment: C++11 has `std::tuple`.